# Self-referential relationships (friends of users) in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-data, active-model-serializers

In Rails 4.0 backend I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: User
end
```

I want to pass the user's friend list into JSON, so I write a serializer:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  has_many :friends, include: true
```

On the ember-side, I'm trying to load the JSON with the following `User` model:

```
Nektere.User = DS.Model.extend
  friends: DS.hasMany('user')
```

but this gives me an error

```
Assertion failed: No model was found for 'friend'
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'typeKey' of undefined
```

It's asking me for a `Friend` model, but a `Friend` is a `User`.  I'm guessing I need to tell ember-data that the `friends` array is actually an array of `User` records, but if `friends: DS.hasMany('user')` doesn't do it, then I don't know how.  How do I load this data structure properly into ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AMS you can specify the root, in your case the root for your friends relationship would be users, something like this should work

```
has_many :friends, include: true, root: :users
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  This seems to sideload a `users` array in the JSON, corresponding to `friend_ids` within the `user` object.  It looks like ember-data is reading this correctly but I need to test it more thoroughly.  I'm curious about how this would work if I needed to sideload two distinct arrays of users, for example `:friends` and `:followers`?  I can't have two arrays both named `users`, can I?